# Python, writing an integer to a '.txt' file

Tags: python, performance, pickle, robustness

Would using the pickle function be the fastest and most robust way to write an integer to a text file?

Here is the syntax I have so far:

```
import pickle

pickle.dump(obj, file)
```

If there is a more robust alternative, please feel free to tell me.

My use case is writing an user input:

```
n=int(input("Enter a number: "))
```

- Yes, A human will need to read it and maybe edit it
- There will be 10 numbers in the file
- Python may need to read it back later.

Comment: What's your use case?

Comment: Oh, sorry for the lack of detail, but I was using it to write an integer(userinput) into a .txt file.

Comment: Your question is still unclear. How will the file be used?  If your program needs to read the file later and retrieve the number, pickle *might* be appropriate. Otherwise, it probably is not.

Comment: The main questions are: Is there any possibility a human will need to read this file? edit it? a non-python program might want to read it? edit it? How much data will be in the file? Will it just be one number? Many numbers?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think it's simpler doing:

```
number = 1337

with open('filename.txt', 'w') as f:
  f.write('%d' % number)
```

But it really depends on your use case.

Comment: I really can't see a difference in speed.

Comment: This code has a pretty legacy feel to it. Old-style string formatting is generally to be avoided in new code, and files should be opened using [the `with` statement](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lRaKmobSXF4&lc=abvyzpzCoB4yV2md5OqJQZgXTd00VmErxY868GfWsEo&lch=email&feature=em-comment_received&lcor=1).

Comment: @Lattyware After much debate I've concluded that old-style string formatting is a stylistic choice, even though `.format` has much greater capabilities, people are still allowed to use it if they wish... `with` should always be used though! Also why use formatting in the first place... `str(number)`

Comment: It's not a matter of 'allowed' or not, simply a matter of style, as you originally state, and the docs do recommend avoiding old-style string formatting in new code, which is really the only style advice on the matter. Generally, when working with any code that someone else might end up reading (which I presume of all my code), it's best to follow the conventions outlined by the language in order to increase readability and familiarity. And yes, the better option here is `str(number)` as you say.

Comment: @Lattyware As much as I would like that to be the case, It's still generally accepted by the Python community

Answer (score 5):

### Write

```
result = 1

f = open('output1.txt','w')  # w : writing mode  /  r : reading mode  /  a  :  appending mode
f.write('{}'.format(result))
f.close()
```

### Read

```
f = open('output1.txt', 'r')
input1 = f.readline()
f.close()

print(input1)
```

Answer (score 1):

The following opens a while and appends the following number to it.

```py
def writeNums(*args):
    with open("f.txt", "a") as f:
        f.write("\n".join([str(n) for n in args]) + "\n")

writeNums(input("Enter a numer:"))
```

Answer (score 1):

With python 2, you can also do:

```
number = 1337

with open('filename.txt', 'w') as f:
  print >>f, number
```

I personally use this when I don't need formatting.

Answer (score 1):

I just encountered a similar problem.
I used a simple approach, saving the integer in a variable, and writing the variable to the file as a string. If you need to add more variables you can always use "a+" instead of "w" to append instead of write.

```
f = open("sample.txt", "w")
integer = 10
f.write(str(integer))
f.close()
```

Later you can use float to read the file and you wont throw and error.