# Saving the int variable in the text file

Tags: python, text, pygame

I would like to save the int variable "**totalbal**" into a text file, so it doesn't resets the variable everytime you quit.

```
import pygame, sys, time
from pygame.locals import *

cpsecond = open("clickpersecond.txt", "r+")
cps = int(cpsecond.read())
baltotal = open("totalbal.txt", "r+")
totalbal = int(baltotal.read())
pygame.init()
    while True: # main game loop
        ...

            if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                totalbal += cps
                savebal = str(totalbal)
                str(baltotal.write(savebal))
                print("Your current money is", savebal, end="\r")
        
        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(30)
```

When you click, it increases the variable "**totalbal**" by **+1**, when you click 8 times, it saves in the text file like **012345678**, i tried to fix it with:

```
int(baltotal.write(savebal))
```

but it didn't worked out.

```
<<< Your current money is 1
<<< Your current money is 2
<<< Your current money is 3
<<< Your current money is 4
<<< Your current money is 5
<<< Your current money is 6
<<< Your current money is 7
<<< Your current money is 8

#The text file output: 012345678
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python, writing an integer to a '.txt' file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16131233/python-writing-an-integer-to-a-txt-file)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to rewrite the file, just close after read and write.

```py
...
with open("totalbal.txt", "r+") as baltotal:
    totalbal = int(baltotal.read())
baltotal.close
...
            if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                totalbal += cps
                with open("totalbal.txt", "w") as baltotal:
                    baltotal.write(str(totalbal))
                baltotal.close
...
```

For clarity in your main process it's probably better to delegate the file write to a function. You should also consider how many times you actually want to write this information; mostly a game state wouldn't need to be recorded that often.

Comment: Tysm, i put the rewrite code outside of the loop!